# How to close md-select on button click inside md-select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

*How can i close my md-select on button click inside md-select window?*

**JS**

```
$scope.closeSelectBox = () => {
  var esc = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  esc.which =  27
  esc.keyCode = 27
  $(document).trigger(esc)
}
```

**HTML**

```
<md-input-container style="max-width: 150px; width: 150">
  <label>Helper:</label>
  <md-select ng-model='vm.selectedHelpers' multiple>
    <md-select-header style="height: 25px">
      <md-button ng-click="closeSelectBox()">Close</md-button>
    </md-select-header>
    <md-option ng-repeat='item in vm.helpers' ng-value='item'>
      {{item.name}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eo4th092/21/)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
Need only trigger click on md-backdrop

```
$("md-backdrop").trigger ("click")
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eo4th092/23/)